# How do I get HTML.Partial to use T4MVC constants?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib, t4mvc

I've started using T4MVC and I'm trying to figure out how use T4MVC with PartialViews.
I currently have

```
@Html.Partial("LocationGrid", Model.Locations)
```

I would like to use

```
@Html.Partial(MVC.Client.Views.LocationGrid, Model.Location)
```

but MVC.Client.Views.LocationGrid returns the full path not the name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though it returns the full path, it works fine as MVC is designed to handle either.

Comment: thanks, it guess it was giving me an unrelated syntax error when I tried before